Kendo Spreadsheet cell focus for angular 13
I'm trying to find the documentation of kendo spreadsheet in angular 13.
sheet.selectCell({ row: 2, col: 1 }); this code is not working.
this.spreadsheet.scrollIntoView(2, 1); not working.
sheet.selectCell({ row: 2, col: 1 });  is not working.
this.spreadsheet.scrollIntoView(2, 1); not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
